ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whois'
I am writing a simple python script to do a whois lookup for a domain in Visual studio code.
I installed python whois using following code.
Pip3 install python-whois
The following is the code:
import whois

domain_whois =  whois.whois("google.com")

print(domain_whois)

I get the following error when ran:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/User1/Documents/Python/addition.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whois
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whois'

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

You're likely not running the script in the same virtual environment you installed the library into. Check what context your script is running in and have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments

Regarding the linked question, look at Brett Cannon's answer first. He's a VSCode and CPython dev.
